# How to get profile information ie..(email id) for configured account

Tags: oauth-2.0, eventbrite

I configured EventBrite account in my application using Oauth 2 authentication. After configuring I have requirement to display profile information of configured account (i. e. e-mail ID). Is there any API to get profile information for configured account?

Answer (score 0):

Try Eventbrite's [user_get](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_get) API call:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_get